# How to implement the Odd even way scrollable list of posted user items on wall

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, swift5

Hello All I hope you all are working well,

I am stuck in a iOS Swift project scenario need help is much appreciated. look out the picture below

[UI to implement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdqrk.jpg)

In that picture need to implement this UI there are response coming from server with random images array object. The images could be in even or odd. In case of odd image need to show the 5 image 1 is at top and followed by 4 images horizontally showing in cell one. and only the 4 images like horizontally in case of Even.

I am confused to implement the same. Anyone can help this, Need t have this for my iOS Application with swift language.

Comment: UICollectionview with two different cell sizes; first cell is full width if odd half width if even. All the rest half width.

Comment: @Paulw11, you are trying to say when there is odd data come then the first image of UICollectionViewCell should be Full Image, and When Even data is come it should be half of collectionView. Does it work well with any number of images. and Does my tableCell Height will show equal height to the content present in collectionView.

Comment: You can set the cell size using the uicollectionview flow layout delegate. Simply look which item you are being asked for (item 0 or other) and check the number of items in your data source (odd or even).  If odd and item 0 return the full width size. If even or not 0 return half width

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 appreciated brother.